# Are pseudo Riemannian manifolds with identical Wilson loops isometric?

Tags: gravity, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, wilson-loop

It is well established that in gauge theory, the Wilson loops of the theory determine the gauge potential up a gauge transformation. That is, two gauge potentials $A_\mu$ and $B_\mu $ produce the same Wilson loops $W[\gamma]$ for all simple closed curves $\gamma$ if and only if there is a gauge transformation relating $A_\mu$ and $B_\mu$ (see R. Giles, Reconstruction of gauge potentials from Wilson loops).

In general relativity, there is a very close analogy to gauge theory, with the Christoffel symbols acting as the gauge potential (though determined by the underlying metric, assuming the Levi-Civita connection). We can then define gravitational Wilson loops by the trace of the parallel transport propagator around simple closed curves. It then seems to me natural to wonder:

If two pseudo-Riemannian manifolds have precisely the same gravitational Wilson loops (meaning there is a smooth invertible map between simple closed curves between the manifolds which preserves the value of the Wilson loop), does that imply the manifolds are isometric to each other? I assume the answer is well-known to mathematicians, but I don't know what they call the result.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, or rather I think it's perhaps using terminology in a non-standard way: What do gauge potentials (either "normal" or Christoffel) have to do with manifolds being diffeomorphic? Manifolds $M,N$ are diffeomorphic if there's a smooth map $f : M\to N$ whose inverse is also smooth (a *diffeomorphism*), this definition makes no references to any connections. There are, for instance, many different connections (=gauge potentials) on $\mathbb{R}^n$, yet all these $\mathbb{R}^n$ remain diffeomorphic even with different values for their Wilson loops (=holonomies).

Comment: I should have said isometric. My question is if I have two pseudo Riemannian manifolds $R = (M, g)$ and $R’ = (M’, g’)$ and the Wilson loops of these manifolds agree in an appropriate sense, does that guarantee these manifolds are isometric to each other?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/339518/143136

Comment: I’ve edited the question to fix my use of diffeomorphic. In order for that link to answer the question, we first need to know if having matching Wilson loops establishes that the connections agree. Is that true?

Comment: You just need to translate the physics terms into the math terms: Two gauge potentials related by a gauge transformation are two connections on the same bundle that are related by a bundle automorphism.